# Flutter - access attribute in List<Map<String, dynamic>>

Tags: flutter, list, loops, dictionary

i have a varibale named `_users` of type `List<Map<String,dynamic>> it has an attribute named email that i'm trying to access

[image]

I tried accessing it like this but it didn't work

```
   var emails = _users.map((element) => element["email"]).toList();
          for (String? element in emails) {
            TaggedUsersSingleton.instance.taggedUsers.add(element);
          }
        }
```

And this is the error that i'm getting

```
════════ Exception caught by foundation library ════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown while dispatching notifications for AnnotationEditingController:
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type
```

Answer (score 0):

The resulting mapping is a list of lists. You would want to flatten it. I believe changing the first line to this might do that:

```
var emails = _users.expand((element) => element["email"]).toList();
```

Example:

```
  List<Map<String,dynamic>> _users = [{'email': ['a']},{'email': ['b']},{'email': ['c', 'd']}];
  var emails = _users.expand((element) => element["email"]).toList();
  for (String? element in emails) {
    print(element);
  }
```

output:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Comment: I have this error now when i made the changes you mention type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Comment: @WassefHassine strange. I've added an example that works fine. I don't know why it doesn't work for you

Comment: I'm not sure but could it be the dart version that i'm working with is causing an issue ? Dart version is : 2.17.6